# Discovering maximum packet size

Tags: windows, unix, networking, udp, mtu

I'm working on a network-related project and I am using DTLS (TLS/UDP) to secure communications.

Reading the specifications for DTLS, I've noted that DTLS requires the **DF** flag (Don't Fragment) to be set.

On my local network if I try to send a message bigger than 1500 bytes, nothing is sent. That makes perfect sense. On Windows the sendto() reports a success but nothing is sent.

I obviously cannot unset the **DF** flag manually since it is mandatory for DTLS and i'm not sure whether the 1500 bytes limit (MTU ?) could change in some situations. I guess it can.

So, my question is : "Is there a way to discover this limit ?" using APIs ?

If not, what would be the lowest possible value ?

My software runs under UNIX (Linux/MAC OSX) and Windows OSes so different solutions for each OS are welcome ;)

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you rolling your own DTLS implementation or something? The RFC suggests that they should check for the  "fragmentation needed and DF set" error and revise the estimated MTU accordingly. http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347.txt

Comment: No, i'm not rolling my own DTLS implementation. I'm using OpenSSL. I need to get the MTU to fragment packets before sending them.

So, i need a way to ensure that my packets are small enough not to be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a minimum MTU that must be supported - 576 bytes, including IP headers.  So if you keep your packets below that, you don't have to worry about PMTU-D (that's what DNS does).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the minimal frame size.

I guess I have no choice but to fragment my frames in 576 bytes parts.

Thank you for that !

Comment: @ereOn: Remember that it's 576 byte IP packets - so that includes the IP & UDP headers, and whatever per-packet DTLS overhead there is.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to 'auto tune' it by sending a range of packet sizes to the target, and see which arrive.  think binary_search ...

Comment: Thanks, but I wish there was some "standard" way to do this. I don't really feel like reinventing MTU Path Discovery.